# Find zeros of function in 2 variables

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions

I have two functions $f(r,\phi)$, and $g(r,\phi)$.

What is the best way to find the curve in the plane $(x,y)$ or $(r,\phi)$, over which $f(r,\phi)=g(r,\phi)$?

I know how to plot it, using `ContourPlot`, but it seems that both `Solve` and `FindRoot` aren't suited to solve my problem. Any help?

**Edit**

My functions are:

```
Q00=1; a=1; k=0.01;

dQ1[r_, ϕ_] = Q00/2 (BesselK[0, k r]/BesselK[0, k a] + BesselK[1, k r]/BesselK[1, k a] Cos[ϕ]);

f[r_, ϕ_] := -(Q00/2) + dQ1[r, ϕ];
g[r_, ϕ_] = Q00 /2 Sin[ϕ] (a/r);
```

The range I am interested in is $a<r<L$, with $L=10$, and $0\leq\phi\leq 2\pi$

Comment: `Plot[Evaluate[
   Interpolation@
    Flatten[Cases[
      ContourPlot[x^2 - x y == x^2 + y^2 - 1, {x, -1, 3}, {y, 0, 3}] //
          Normal, Line[x__] :> x, Infinity], 1]][
  x], {x, -1, 3}]`

Comment: With knowing the exact form of the functions it is easier to helping you.
but you can try numberic solving. other form of those functions if be exist and so on.

Comment: I edited the question, maybe you could expand on that, thanks!

Comment: one of the functions is x^2 - x y == x^2 + y^2 - 1 what is another function? @usumdelphini

Comment: That is not my function, my functions are in the question, not in the comments.

Comment: @belisariushassettled, that doesn't work if it is double valued, for example if you set your ranges to `{-10,10}` then you get two curves.  This will work:  `Plot[Evaluate[
  Through[Map[Interpolation, 
     Cases[Normal[
       ContourPlot[
        x^2 - x y == x^2 + y^2 - 1, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]], 
      Line[x__] :> x, Infinity]][x]]], {x, -10, 10}]` but it doesn't work for every set of two functions.

Comment: For example if the two functions are equal along a vertical line, you can't interpolate that as a function.  @usumdelphini, what value of `Q00` do you use?  What numerical range of r and phi values do you want to solve over?

Comment: @JasonB It wasn't an answer, but a quick one liner. I'm sure this is a dupe, though

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275)?

Comment: @JasonB Edited again to answer your questions

Comment: related possible dup : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75352/2079

Comment: you should give values for `a,k,L` as well.

Comment: @george2079 Done, sorry

Comment: If you want a single point this works: `FindMinimum[ (f[r, p] - g[r, p])^2, {{r, 2}, {p, 4}}] `.  Really if you want nicely connected curves, extracting the data from `ContourPlot` is the way to go though. (see links in other comments)

Answer (score 3):

Just changing range of $\phi$ from $-\pi$ to $\pi$:

```
cp = ContourPlot[f[x, y] - g[x, y], {x, 0, 10}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, 
   Contours -> {0}, ContourShading -> None];
fun = Cases[cp, Line[x__] :> x, -1];
pts = cp[[1, 1]];
t = pts[[fun[[1]]]];
{xd, yd} = Transpose[t];
xf = ListInterpolation[xd, {0, 1}]
yf = ListInterpolation[yd, {0, 1}]
```

You can recover for range 0 to $2 \pi$:

```
pp = ParametricPlot[Mod[{xf[t], yf[t]}, 2 Pi], {t, 0, 1}, 
  Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 2 Pi}}, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic]
Row[{pp, ContourPlot[f[x, y] - g[x, y], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   Contours -> {0}, ContourShading -> None, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic]}]
```

[image]

Confirming (on $-\pi$ to $\pi$ range for convenience):

```
h[t_] := {xf[t], yf[t]};
p1 = Plot3D[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, 0, 10}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, 
   Mesh -> False];
p2 = ParametricPlot3D[{xf[t], yf[t], f @@ h[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.02]}];
Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

maybe this give you some Idea :

```
Plot[Evaluate@
  Table[Evaluate[f[x, y] /. {a -> 2, k -> 3}] - 
    Evaluate[g[x, y] /. {a -> 4}], {y, 1, 10}], {x, 0.01, 10}]
```

at least we can guess that for `0<x<10` the y answer should be between 0 and 4 for these parameter's value.

[image]

I know this is not an answer but I don't know how can I post my comments (I am under 50 reputation)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at ContourPlot, we should be able to get an idea of where the roots are:

```
ContourPlot[
 f[r, ϕ] == g[r, ϕ], {r, 1, 10}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

We can then use With and Table to get the roots.

```
In[16]:= Table[
 With[{r = r1}, 
  FindRoot[f[r, ϕ] == g[r, ϕ], {ϕ, 0.5}]], {r1, 1, 4, 
  0.5}]

Out[16]= {{ϕ -> 0.785398}, {ϕ -> 0.694063}, {ϕ -> 
   0.575969}, {ϕ -> 0.434701}, {ϕ -> 0.268362}, {ϕ -> 
   0.0677875}, {ϕ -> -0.196409}}
```