# Creating a white and black color function

Tags: plotting, graphics, color

What I want to get is a density plot where the color function is thresholded: if the value of a function is larger a threshold, the color function returns white; otherwise, black.

I found some tutorials about how to create gradient color functions, but didn't find one for any thresholded color function.

If any of you teach this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** An alternative way to use `ContourPlot` using `threshold` as the single `Contour` with the option `ContourShading`:

```
threshold = .5;    
ContourPlot[FractionalPart[y + Sin[x^2 + 3 y]], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  Contours -> {threshold}, ContourShading -> {Black, White}, 
  Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 90]
```

[image]

Similarly, `DensityPlot` with `MeshFunctions`, `Mesh` and `MeshShading` options:

```
DensityPlot[FractionalPart[y + Sin[x^2 + 3 y]], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{threshold}}, 
 MeshShading -> {Black, White}, PlotPoints -> 90, 
 Exclusions -> None, WorkingPrecision -> 10]
```

[image]

And, a combination of `Raster` and `Image`:

```
Image @ Raster[Table[UnitStep[FractionalPart[y + Sin[x^2 + 3 y]] - threshold], 
 {y, -3, 3,  1/100}, {x, -3, 3, 1/100}]]
```

[image]

We get the same picture using `Boole[FractionalPart[y + Sin[x^2 + 3 y]] >= threshold]` instead of `UnitStep[FractionalPart[y + Sin[x^2 + 3 y]] - threshold]`.

**Original answer:**

You can use `ContourPlot` with options `Contours` and `ContourShading`:

```
threshold = .5;
ContourPlot[y + Sin[x^2 + 3 y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  Contours -> {threshold}, ContourShading -> {Black, White}]
```

[image]

Another alternative is to use `RegionPlot`:

```
RegionPlot[y + Sin[x^2 + 3 y] <= threshold, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3} , 
 BoundaryStyle -> Black, PlotStyle -> Black, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

With `DensityPlot` you can do

```
DensityPlot[y + Sin[x^2 + 3 y] , {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  ColorFunction -> (Black &), RegionFunction -> (#3 <= threshold &)]
```

[image]

You can also use `DensityPlot` with the option `ColorFunction` with large enough value for `PlotPoints` to get a similar picture the one above:

```
cf1 = If[# <= threshold, Black, White] &;
DensityPlot[y + Sin[x^2 + 3 y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  ColorFunction -> cf1, PlotPoints -> 250]
```

[image]

Using `cf2 = Blend[{Black, White}, UnitStep[# - threshold]] &;` in place of `cf1` gives the same result.

Comment: As a curiosity, why `Density` plot is less clear than `ContourPlot` in general?

Comment: @TaikiBessho, I meant  the blending of colors, for example, `DensityPlot[y + Sin[x^2 + 3 y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 ColorFunction -> (If[# <= threshold, Black, White] &)]` unless you use some additional trick.

Comment: The function I want to plot is something like "FractionalPart[y + Sin[x^2 + 3 y]]". In this case, `ContourPlot` doesn't seem to miss the internal valleys of the function but `RegionPlot` and `DensityPlot` miss them, even when I set `PlotPoints=100` or something. Is this a general feature? Does `CotourPlot` the least likely miss the internal structure which the pred. returns true? Does `ContourPlot` solve the pred. analytically?

Comment: My question above might relate this one:
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75352/is-mathematica-contourplot-function-really-so-efficient

Comment: @TaikiBessho,  you might want to add the option  `MaxRecursion` with a high enough value (say 7) to `DensityPlot and `RegionPlot`. I don't know the internal workings of `ContourPlot`.

Comment: Wait, the results given by the first 2 samples are wrong, aren't they?: `Plot[FractionalPart[y + Sin[x^2 + 3 y]] /. x -> 0 // Evaluate, {y, -3, 3}]`

Comment: Thank you @xzczd; adding `Exclusions->None` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You may consider `Image` and `Binarize`:

```
expr = FractionalPart[y + Sin[x^2 + 3 y]];

Binarize[Image@Reverse@Transpose@Table[expr, {x, -3, 3, 0.01}, {y, -3, 3, 0.01}], 0.5]
```

If you need the frame, `ArrayPlot` and `UnitStep` may be a better choice:

```
frame = DensityPlot[, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}];

binarize = {x, threshold} \[Function] 
           Evaluate@Simplify`PWToUnitStep@Piecewise[{{1, x < threshold}}]

frame~Show~ArrayPlot[
  binarize[Table[expr, {x, -3, 3, 0.01}, {y, -3, 3, 0.01}]\[Transpose], 0.5], 
  DataReversed -> True, DataRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

If one really wishes to use `DensityPlot[]` (even tho the other answers have already shown better approaches), you need to remember to set `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` before using a thresholded color function. In the following example, I combine `GrayLevel[]` and `UnitStep[]`:

```
With[{h = 1/2},
     DensityPlot[y + Sin[x^2 + 3 y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
                 ColorFunction -> Function[z, GrayLevel[UnitStep[z - h]]], 
                 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotPoints -> 205]]
```

[image: monochrome thresholded plot]

More generally, one can use `Blend[]` and `Boole[]` for such plots:

```
With[{h = 1/2},
     DensityPlot[y + Sin[x^2 + 3 y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
                 ColorFunction -> Function[z, Blend[{Pink, Green}, Boole[z > h]]], 
                 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotPoints -> 205]]
```

[image: colored version]