# Solving a function inside an integral

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I have an integral without a closed form answer and is given by,

$$a = c z_s^{d+1}\int_0^1 dx \frac{x^d}{\sqrt{(1-(z_s/z_h)^{d+1} x^{d+1})(1-c^2 z_s^{2d} x^{2d})}} \tag{1}\label{1}$$

where $a$, $z_s$, and $z_h$ are constants which can be assigned a value ($0 \leq a, z_s \leq 10$, $z_h=10$), $c=c(z_s)$ is an unknown function of $z_s$ which I need to determine from $\eqref{1}$.

After determining $c(z_s)$ in terms of $z_s$ I will plug that into the expression $S$ given by,

\begin{align}
S &= \frac{1}{4 z_s^{d-1}}\Bigg(1 -\frac{\sqrt{(1-c^2 z_s^{2d})(1-b^{d+1})}}{d-1} + \frac{2d-1}{d-1} c^2 z_s^{2d} \int^1_0 dx x^d \sqrt{\frac{(1-(b x)^{d+1})}{(1-c^2(z_s x)^{2d})}}\\  
  & -\frac{b^{d+1}(d+1)}{2(d-1)} \int^1_0 dx x \sqrt{\frac{(1-c^2(z_s x)^{2d})}{(1-(b x)^{d+1})}}\\ 
& + b^{d+1}\int^1_0 dx \frac{x}{\sqrt{(1-(b x)^{d+1})(1-c^2(z_s x)^{2d})}}\Bigg) \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align}

where $b=\frac{z_s}{z_h}$.

I have tried the following code

```
d = 3;
zh = 10;
SeedRandom[2020];
a = RandomReal[{0, 10}];
toroot[c_?NumericQ, z_] := a - c*z^(d + 1)*NIntegrate[x^d*((1 - (z/zh)^(d + 1) x^(d + 1)) (1 - c^2*z^(2 d) x^(2 d)))^(-1/2), {x, 0, 1}]
cz[z_?NumericQ] := c /. FindRoot[toroot[c, z], {c, 0.002, 0.0000001, 10}]
ints[x_?NumericQ, z_] := With[{b = z/zh}, (((2 d - 1)/(d - 1)) cz[z]^2 z^(2 d)) x^d ((1 - (b x)^(d + 1))/(1 - cz[z]^2 (z x)^(2 d)))^(1/2) - ((b^(d + 1) (d + 1))/(2 (d - 1))) x ((1 - cz[z]^2 (z x)^(2 d))/(1 - (b x)^(d + 1)))^(1/2) + (b^(d + 1) x)/((1 - (b x)^(d + 1)) (1 - cz[z]^2 (z x)^(2 d)))^(1/2)];
intS[z_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[ints[x, z], {x, 0.5, 1}]
functionS[z_?NumericQ] := ((-((1 - cz[z]^2 z^(2 d)) (1 - b^(d + 1)))^(1/2)/(d - 1)) + intS[z] + 1)/(4 z^(d - 1));
function[z_?NumericQ] := Log[10, functionS[z]];
Plot[function[z], {z, 0, 10}, PlotPoints -> 3, AxesLabel -> {"z", "Log S"}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}, PlotRange -> Full, ImageSize -> Large]
```

How should I obtain an expression or at least a numerical fit of $c(z_s)$ in terms of $z_s$ given that $\eqref{1}$ does not have a closed form? Maybe Mathematica has a way to give a relation even it is not exact, like determining the integral using approximate methods? In the end, I will plug $c(z_s)$ in $S$ and plot.

***Note: This is an updated version of my original question, I have removed the redundancies in my original post and clarified my problem.

Comment: Regarding your last block: there errors you have got are due to _MMA_ not substituting the value of `z` (because of `b` for instance).

Comment: @anderstood So the fix there is to add the function `With`?

Comment: Not only, I also introduced the dependencies explicitly (this way I can test that each function is evaluated as I expect), used `SetDelayed` instead of `=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is: given $a,d,z$, find a $c$ that corresponds to a root of $f(c)=a-cz_s\int \dots$. It happens that here, you want $f$ to involve numerical integration.

```
d = 3;
SeedRandom[2020];
a = RandomReal[{0, 10}];
toroot[c_?NumericQ, z_] := 
 a - c*z^(d + 1)*NIntegrate[x^d*(1 - c^2*z^(2 d) x^(2 d))^(-1/2), {x, 0, 1}]
cz[z_?NumericQ] := c /. FindRoot[toroot[c, z], {c, 0.002, 0.0000001, 10}]

Plot[cz[z], {z, 0.4, 5}, PlotPoints -> 3, AxesLabel -> {"z", "c[z]"}]
```

[image]

And that the same plot, in red, on your 3D plot:

[image]

Note: Depending on the values of the parameters $a,d,z$, you might have issues in the numerical integration.

Note 2: If, when changing the integrands or playing with the parameters, the above approach is not robust enough, you might want to use numerical continuation to retrieve $c(z)$ from one pair $(c(z_0), z_0)$.

---

**Another approach** based on `ContourPlot`: extract the slice from your 3D plot with `ContourPlot`, extract the points from the plot, interpolate. It is not as accurate (see [Is Mathematica `ContourPlot` function really so efficient?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75352/is-mathematica-contourplot-function-really-so-efficient)) but it is easy to understand.

```
contour = ContourPlot[inta[zs, c] == a, {zs, 0, 2}, {c, 0, 10}, 
   PlotPoints -> 10] // Quiet
data = contour[[1, 1, 1]];
cinter = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
   Plot[{cinter[x], cz[x]}, {x, 0.4, 2}, PlotLabels -> {"FindRoot", "ContourPlot"}]
```

[image]

---

Regarding your edit: your syntax does not allow MMA to know the value of `z` when it integrates, hence the error message.

The following works:

```
ints[x_?NumericQ, z_] := 
  With[{b = 
     z/zh}, ((((2 d - 1)/(d - 1)) cz[z]^2 z^(2 d)) x^
         d (1 - (b x)^(d + 1))^(1/2))/(1 - 
        cz[z]^2 z^(2 d) x^(2 d)) (((b^(d + 1) (d + 1))/(2 (d - 
              1))) x (1 - cz[z]^2 z^(2 d) x^(2 d))^(1/
           2))/(1 - (b x)^(d + 1))^(1/
         2) + (b^(d + 1) x)/((1 - (b x)^(d + 1))^(1/2) (1 - 
          cz[z]^2 z^(2 d) x^(2 d))^(1/2))];
intS[z_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[ints[x, z], {x, 0.5, 1}]
functionS = (-((1 - cz[z]^2 z^(2 d)) (1 - b^(d + 1)))^(1/2)/(d - 1) - 
     intS[z] + 1/z^(d - 1))/4;
function = Log[10, functionS];

function /. z -> 0.5
(* -0.0560923 *)

function /. z-> 2.
(* -1.20545 + 1.36438 I *)

Plot[function, {z, 0.4, 1.3}, PlotPoints -> 3, AxesLabel -> {"z", "Log S"}]
```

[image]

Note however that `function` is complex-valued on some domains, so you cannot always plot it directly.

Comment: This seems to be pertaining to the first expression for $a$ which has a closed form but please look at my UPDATE post. I have tried to use your code corresponding to the update in my post, but it seems to be not working since it shows "The integrand has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,1}}."

Comment: @mathemania If you read and understand the answer, you'll see that I use nowhere the closed-form expression (btw I use `NIntegrate`).

Comment: Yes, but when you substitute it in $S$ and do a plot it brings out an error message as in my first comment. Does this have anything to do with $c$ or the expression of $S$ itself?

Comment: @mathemania See edit

Comment: I see, but what if the range of evaluation for $z_s$ is $[0,10]$, is there a way to chop this to avoid those complex values?

Comment: For $z=2$, `function` yields: `-1.20545 + 1.36438 I`. You can't chop that. I presume the complex values come from the square root of something negative (maybe $\sqrt(1-c^2)$ since $c$ reaches $10$. Any reason why you would expect real values?

Comment: I see, I did a big revision in my post, I removed the first part of the OP as that confuses people of my true question which is in the last part of my OP. I noticed that I missed a factor of `z` in the expression for $\eqref{2}$. I also rewrote the code and checked everything.

Comment: How do you set the values of `cz` in your `FindRoot`, that is, `FindRoot[toroot[c, z], {c, 0.002, 0.0000001, 10}]` ? Depending on the situation changing 0.002 to 1 will give a result saying that it encountered a singular Jacobian at that point, so what are the things I need to know in setting those starting value, min value and max value?

Comment: @mathemania You wrote that $c\in [0,10]$, so that should be of the form `{c, c0, 0, 10}`. For `c0`, it should be as closed from the solution as possible. `FindRoot` implements a Newton--Raphson method (I believe), so the convergence is not guaranteed. However, you could use an initial condition from the `ContourPlot` (second approach in my answer) to make the whole procedure robust.

Answer (score 2):

```
ListLinePlot@
 NDSolveValue[{x'[z] == 1, x[1] == 1, toroot[c[z], z] == 0, 
   c[1] == cz[1]}, c, {z, 0.4, 5}]
```

[image: Respoasdf]

Comment: This seems to be pertaining to the first expression for $a$ which has a closed form so it is not really an issue on how to evaluate it using the usual `NIntegrate` and `FindRoot` but please look at my UPDATE post.

Comment: @mathemania When I looked at the Q (the first time), there was only one bit of code for the integral.  Are you saying that it not the integral you wanted help with?

Comment: Yes there was only one bit of code which corresponds to the first $a$ integral which has a closed form answer, but my question is how to evaluate an integral in general even in the case where there is no closed form answer which I posted in my UPDATE.

Comment: I think there is already nothing wrong with $cz[z]$, it is when you plug it in $S$ where problem occurs.

Comment: Interesting combination of `ListLinePlot` with `InterpolatingFunction`.

Comment: @mathemania Perhaps it's because `intS` is defined incorrectly (I thought someone already pointed it out, but I can't find the remark). Try `intS[z0_?NumericQ] := 
  Block[{z = z0}, NIntegrate[ints, {x, 0, 1}]];` -- There's no `z` in the code body of the def., so the arg. `z_` won't replace anything.  Then my `cz` (= the value of `NDSolveValue`) will be quicker than yours.

Comment: @MIchaelE2 What do you mean by `intS` is incorrectly defined? How? Also how should I  write `intS[z0_?NumericQ]` along with `NDSolveValue`? I mean, where should I insert `NDSolveValue`? What do you mean by there is no `z` in the code?

Comment: @mathemania The letter `z` is not found in the code body, which is `NIntegrate[ints, {y, 0, 1}]` (`ints` is not evaluated until after all literally occurring instances of `z` have been replaced; any instances of `z` in the value of `ints` are not replaced).  The variable `y` is not found in the value of the expression `ints`. Set `cz = NDSolveValue[<rest of code>]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 I'm sorry for the earlier confusion of my post. I did a big revision since my OP confuses people about my true question. I also noticed that I missed a factor of `z` in $\eqref{2}$, I checked everything and rewrote my question to make it clear.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Did you convert the integral to an ODE when you wrote `x'[z]==1, x[1]==1`? What does `c[1]==cz[1]` mean?

Comment: @mathemania (1) The `x'[t] == 1` provides a dummy ODE to drive `NDSolve` to construct the solution to `toroot[c[z], z] == 0`. It's called a [DAE](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveDAE.html). `NDSolve` is programmed to require at least one differential equation, so I threw in a dummy one. (2)  `c[1] == cz[1]` sets the value of `c[1]` to the value returned by (your) `cz[z]` function.  It's the initial condition.  The code might work without it. `NDSolve` calls `FindRoot` with a starting guess you can't control, so I usually give it explicitly.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I see, is it possible for you to check my code one last time to see if there is anything wrong or you have more suggestions for me to improve on?

Answer (score 0):

First the obvious part: performing the integral gives the equation

$$
a = \frac{c z^{d+1} \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{d+1}{2 d};\frac{3 d+1}{2 d};c^2 z^{2d}\right)}{d+1}
$$

Substitute $x=c z^d$:
$$
\frac{a}{z} = \frac{x \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{d+1}{2 d};\frac{3 d+1}{2 d};x^2\right)}{d+1}
$$

For any given value of $\frac{a}{z}$ satisfying $\left|\frac{a}{z}\right|\le \frac{\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(\frac{3 d+1}{2 d}\right)}{(d+1) \Gamma \left(\frac{2d+1}{2 d}\right)}$ you can find the corresponding value of $x$ (and therefore of $c=x/z^d$) by numerical solving,

```
With[{az = 0.2, d = 3},
  FindRoot[az == (x*Hypergeometric2F1[1/2,(d+1)/(2d),(3d+1)/(2d),x^2])/(d+1),
           {x, az*(d+1)}]]
(*    {x -> 0.705645}    *)
```

where the starting point of the root search, $x_0\approx\frac{a}{z}(d+1)$, is found from the linear approximation of the hypergeometric term for small $x$.

All packaged up in one function,

```
cc[d_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] :=
  x/z^d /. FindRoot[a/z == (x*Hypergeometric2F1[1/2,(d+1)/(2d),(3d+1)/(2d),x^2])/(d+1),
                    {x, a/z*(d+1)}]

cc[3, 0.2, 1]
(*    0.705645    *)
```

Alternatively, assuming that $\left|\frac{a}{z}\right|$ is very small, you could use a series-approximation of the hypergeometric series,

```
Series[(x*Hypergeometric2F1[1/2,(d+1)/(2d),(3d+1)/(2d),x^2])/(d+1), {x, 0, 4}]
(*    x/(d+1) + x^3/(6d+2) + O(x^5)    *)
```

Use this for cubic (or even higher-order) root-finding:

```
f3[az_, d_] = Root[Function[x, x/(1 + d) + x^3/(2 (1 + 3 d)) - az], 1];
f3[0.2, 3]
(*    0.724076    *)

f5[az_, d_] = Root[Function[x, x/(1 + d) + x^3/(2 (1 + 3 d)) + (3 x^5)/(8 (1 + 5 d)) - az], 1];
f5[0.2, 3]
(*    0.711057    *)
```

In all these [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects I've picked the first root because it is the only real-valued one.

Comment: Nice, is there a way to do a `FindRoot` as a list? That is, in your code containing `cc[d_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ]` is it possible to input a range of `z` so that it outputs a range of `cc`? I'm thinking of `Table` but seems like it is not working.

Comment: Try `Table[{cc[3, 0.2, z]}, {z, 1, 10, 1/2}]` or `Plot[cc[3, 0.2, z], {z, 1, 10}]`.

Comment: Your suggestion worked, but how to do this if the integral does not have a closed form just like the hypergeometric function? Please see the update on my question.

Comment: `Integrate[x^d/Sqrt[1 - c^2*x^(2*d)], x]==(x^(1 + d)*Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, (1 + d)/(2*d), (1/2)*(3 + 1/d), c^2*x^(2*d)])/(1 + d)`. Seems important.